# Android Lollipop system icons in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I get the Android Lollipop system icons in Android Studio for use in my app? I am strictly working on Lollipop and whenever I try and do `android:icon="@android/drawable/...` I always get old Kit Kat era icons. I want the icons referred to on this page [here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons). But I get stuff like this:

[image]

**EDIT:** Found a neat little plugin available for Android Studio. I created an answer to this question. Hopefully it will help others in the future who are looking to do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more digging I found a great solution. Not quite exactly built in but it is a great alternative and I didn't find a 100% definitive answer on here so I'll make this post for future people.

So there is this plugin for Android Studio called [Android Drawable Importer](https://plus.google.com/wm/1/+MarcPrengemann/posts/R4QeK7RnQnE) by a man named **Marc Prengemann** that will allow you to import whichever icons from the Lollipop system icons, given that you download them first.

To download them go [here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/sticker-sheets-icons.html) and you can download, they are also available on github. But, the plugin also offers the ability to download them. Your choice.

So to get the plugin go to:

**WINDOWS:** `File > Settings > Plugins > Browse Repositories`

**MAC:** `Android Studio > Preferences > Plugins > Browse Repositories`

and at the top search for Android Drawable Importer. It should look similar to this:

[image]

Click install and Android Studio will need to restart.

Next you are going to have to go back to:

**WINDOWS:** `File > Settings > Android Drawable Importer`

**MAC:** `Android Studio > Preferences > Other Settings > Android Drawable Importer`

and here is where you either download the icon pack or provide the path you stored them if you previously downloaded them (that's what I did here). It will look similar to this:

[image]

Now you are good to go. To add an asset to you project, right click on

**WINDOWS/MAC:** `Drawable > New > MaterialIcons Import` like so:

[image]

You will get a nice little popup window like this that will allow you to look through the different categories like *alert* or *hardware* or *social* and choose the icon, size, and which dimensions you want (hdpi, xhdpi, etc..):

[image]

Hope this helps some folks in the future. You don't only have to use it for material design icons, you could put whatever icons you want in the root path. Again, I didn't make this, just sharing the wealth.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your target android version and also on the version you use for rendering in android studio.
Open the preview panel on the right of your xml, on the top left you can choose 'Android version to use when rendering in the IDE'. That only changes what you see in the IDE though.
Your app theme could also be responsible.